# Why can't I use the `pos_type` return type in the code below?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, fstream

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28%22IOSFWD/STD%3a%3aBASIC_FSTREAM%3a%3aTELLG%22%29;k%28%22STD%3a%3aBASIC_FSTREAM%3a%3aTELLG%22%29;k%28TELLG%29;k%28DevLang-%22C%2b%2b%22%29;k%28TargetOS-WINDOWS%29&rd=true) is the definition of the function `basic_istream::tellg()` in VS2010. Note that the function returns a variable of type `pos_type`. However when I replace the type `streamoff`used in the example, given below, by `pos_type`, the compiler complains (C2065: 'pos_type' : undeclared identifier).

`pos_type` is defined in `<fstream>` as `typedef typename _Traits::pos_type pos_type;`.

```
// basic_istream_tellg.cpp
// compile with: /EHsc
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    ifstream file;
    char c;
    streamoff i; // compiler complains if I replace streamoff by pos_type

    file.open("basic_istream_tellg.txt");
    i = file.tellg();
    file >> c;
    cout << c << " " << i << endl;

    i = file.tellg();
    file >> c;
    cout << c << " " << i << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot just write `pos_type` without qualification. Note that it is a member of `ifstream`. So you've to write this:

```
ifstream::pos_type i; //ok
```

That should work now.

Also, since `using namespace std;` [is considered bad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-a-bad-practice-in-c), you should avoid it, and instead should prefer using full qualification as:

```
std::ifstream file;        //fully-qualified
std::ifstream::pos_type i; //fully-qualified
```

In C++11, you can use `auto` instead.

```
auto i = file.tellg();
```

and let the compiler deduce `i` to be `std::ifstream::pos_type`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: or better use `auto` keyword and don't mess with concrete type

Comment: Perfect. I'm accepting your answer, as it was the first I got. As for the `using namespace std;` I just copied the code from MSDN. Thanks.

Comment: The `using namespace std;` in this example is at least in function scope, which is the least smelly place to use it.

Comment: @aschepler: I think it doesn't make *much* difference because most code are usually in the functions itself. Writing `using namespace std;` at namespace level, and writing `using namespace std;` in every function is *almost* same thing.

Answer (score 0):

`pos_type` is a member typedef which belongs to a class, not a namespace-scope typedef.  You need something like `ifstream::pos_type`.

Answer (score 0):

```
std::ifstream file;        
std::ifstream::pos_type i;
```

you can use this : It works for me in dev C++

```
 i = file.tellg();
```